# How to evaluate the expectation of product of Matrices

Tags: matrices, expectation

Let $\textbf{a}$  be in the random vector in the form of
$$\textbf{a} = \begin{bmatrix} e^{-j k_1 cos(\theta)} & e^{-j k_2 cos(\theta)} & \cdots & e^{-j k_N cos(\theta)} \end{bmatrix}$$
where $k$s are all constants and $\theta$ is a random variable with known distribution.

How do I go on evaluating
$$E_\theta[\textbf{a}^H X \textbf{a}]$$
where $X$ is a complex matrix independent of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}_\theta[{\bf a}^H~ {\bf X}~{\bf a}] &=& \mathbb{E}_\theta
\left[\sum_{mn}a_m^*X_{mn}a_{mn} \right]\\
&=&\sum_{mn}X_{mn}\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[e^{jk_m\cos\theta} e^{-jk_n\cos\theta}] \\
&=& \sum_{mn}X_{mn} \mathbb{E}_\theta[e^{jk_{mn}\cos\theta}] ~~~\mbox{with}~~~k_{km} = k_m - k_n
\end{eqnarray}

The problem is reduced to calculating this last expected value, but that depends on the the PDF of $\theta$

$$
\mathbb{E}_\theta[e^{jk_{mn}\cos\theta}] = \int {\rm d}\theta~ e^{jk_{mn}\cos\theta}f(\theta)
$$